# Redux saga receives function not object as action

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I'm in the process of converting some of my code to use redux-saga (I previously had just redux-thunk but now run them both side-by-side) and have used [this example as a basis](https://github.com/stjepangolemac/monitor-saga/blob/master/src/saga.js).

The only problem I've run up against is using the following function as an argument to `takeEvery` sometimes works as expected, but other times breaks because it receives a function rather than an action object.

```
const requestAction = action => action.type.includes('REQUEST');

function* watchAuthenticationStatus() {
  yield takeEvery(requestAction, ensureAuthenticated);
}
```

Logging the action out from inside `requestAction` shows me that a bunch of the time my actions come through as objects as expected e.g.

```
{ type: "data/FETCH_REQUEST", data: Array(1) }
```

However, I also see a lot of this type of thing:

```
ƒ (_x) {
  return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
}

ƒ (_x2, _x3) {
  return _ref3.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I got around this for the time being by doing a check to see if `action.type` exists, but is anyone able to explain why I see these anonymous functions at times?

**EDIT**

As requested below, I checked the ordering of my middleware, I originally had:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, thunk))
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

Re-ordering saga and thunk to the following fixed my problem:

```
composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, sagaMiddleware))
```

Comment: You mention you're using thunks as well. Could you show us how you set up your middleware (ie, which ones and in which order)?

Comment: Looks like some currying is going on?

Comment: @NicholasTower have edited my question with the answer to your question, and in doing so solved the problem by re-ordering my middlewares. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-ordering the middleware fixed this, originally it looked like this:

```
composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, thunk))
```

Placing thunk first fixed the issue:

```
composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, sagaMiddleware))
```